# Undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I wrote this very simple block of code that does everything I expect it to- however, at the end of the output I always get the error message "Undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)". How/why does this come up, and how can I fix it?

```
def fizzblam

range =* (1..100)
range.each do |i|
if range[i] % 7 == 0 && range[i] % 5 == 0
puts "fizzblam"
elsif range[i] % 7 == 0 && range[i] % 5 != 0
puts "blam"
elsif range[i] % 7 != 0 && range[i] % 5 == 0
puts "fizz"
else puts range[i]
end
end
end

fizzblam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of `range` are 1 to 100, but the indices into `range` are 0 to 99. The `each` method already gives you the elements of the array, not the indices — just use `i` inside the loop body instead of `range[i]`.

You would have gotten a more reasonable error if you indexed an array `a` with `a.fetch(i)` instead of `a[i]` — the former throws `IndexError` while the latter gives `nil`.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir! I figured it had something to with the index. Much appreciate it!

Comment: Very good additional information on the fetch call as opposed to Array[].